# upload file button text change

Tags: json, button, file-upload

I need to alter the name of the file upload button in JSON, but I'm not sure how to achieve

Json script

[image]

output of current Json

[image]

Expecting this output

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please dont post pictures of code, just copy and pasting will suffice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something the button name is fixed for all the places that we use the control with the value `attachmentFormQuestionComponent.uploadFile`. So we can't change it based on specific scenarios. We can only change the label of the field over the button.

[image]